# data.tables is empty - community visualization in DataStudio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm trying to draw custom graph with Google DataStudio community visualization and BigQuery source.

But even if data is exist and valid(check with other basic chart), input data of my drawViz function is empty.

See below Javascript code:

```
function drawViz(data) {
  let rowData = data.tables.DEFAULT;
  var metricName = data.fields['barMetric'][0].name;
  var dimensionName = data.fields['barDimension'][0].name;

  title = metricName + ' by ' + dimensionName + '2';
  console.log(rowData , title )
}
```

Console output:

`> {DEFAULT : Array(0)} "my metrics by my dimension"`

Is there any restriction using community visualization functionality with bigquery?

Or need any additional setting except in codelab (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-visualization/#0) ?

** update
manifest.json : https://storage.googleapis.com/vd-qoe-bucket/test/manifest.json
myViz.json : https://storage.googleapis.com/vd-qoe-bucket/test/myViz.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your links:

The "data" part of your config appears to be invalid:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "concepts",
      "label": "Concepts",
      "elements": [ // setting metric and dimension counts
        {
          "id": "barDimension",
          "label": "Dimension",
          "type": "DIMENSION",
          "options": {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "barMetric",
          "label": "Metric",
          "type": "METRIC",
          "options": {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Removing the comment `// setting dimensions...` should work.